# How to make EJS show only one document inside an array of documents?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Below is the EJS code I am using to show the data.

```
<p class="text-center">Details : <%= user.transactions %></p>
```

When I put in the above code in my EJS, the result is it prints all the documents inside the the "transactions" array document.

```
Details : { date: Thu May 18 2017 11:29:38 GMT+0000 (UTC), credit: 125000, debit: 120000, _id: 591d85a2a86f562d7dcacfd1, description: 'The first post', billno: 123 }
```

How do I make it to only print a particular item like debit or credit or bill number in the page and not the whole array documents?I tried "user.transactions.billno" but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to loop through your transactions.

```
<% user.transactions.forEach(function (transaction) { %>
  <p class="text-center">Bill #: <%= transaction.billno %></p>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Hi, it worked. Thanks a lot. I was wondering if you could explain what is going on in this code, specifically with that transaction as an argument for that function.

Comment: @HishamMubarak `user.transactions` is an Array, I am just calling [Array.protoype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on it.